# Why does OSGI bundle with ActorSystemActivator fail with Logger timeout upon start?

Tags: scala, osgi, akka

I wrote an OSGI "Hello World" app in Scala using the `akka-osgi_2.10-2.3.4` library and all the needed dependencies. Actually here are all the dependencies maven reports:

```
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:jar:2.3.4:compile
|  \- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.2.1:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.10:jar:2.3.4:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
+- org.apache.felix:org.osgi.core:jar:1.4.0:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-osgi_2.10:jar:2.3.4:compile
|  +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.3.1:compile
|  \- org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium:jar:4.3.1:compile
+- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:compile
```

The app uses the simplest possible `Activator` class that takes advantage of the default `start` and `stop` methods offered by `ActorSystemActivator`. The `Activator` class code looks as follows:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
import akka.osgi.ActorSystemActivator

class Activator extends ActorSystemActivator {

  def configure(bundleContext: BundleContext, system: ActorSystem): Unit = {
  }
}
```

I use IBM JDK 1.7 and in the eclipse juno-64 (on ubuntu 12.04) environment I set `bootdelegation` in `config.ini` as described in the official [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/additional/osgi.html):

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=sun.misc
```

I started Eclipse with the `-console` argument and I deployed the bundled app in the OSGi framework. This is what I'm getting when I run `ss` in the OSGi console:

```
426     <<LAZY>>    test-osgi_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
```

The issue I have is with starting the bundle. When I try to start it:

```
osgi> start 426
```

I get an Akka timeout exception:

```
[WARN] [01/06/2015 15:04:02.530] [Gogo shell] [EventStream(akka://bundle-426-ActorSystem)] Logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger did not respond within Timeout(25000 milliseconds) to InitializeLogger(bus)
error while starting up loggers
akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger] due to [akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger did not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead [TIMEOUT]]
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:114)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:113)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
...
```

I checked online and I found issues similar to mine but none of the suggested solutions worked for me. I tried modifying the default logger response timeout to different values, I changed the DefaultLogger with other versions (DefaultOSGiLogger), I added the **org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=sun.misc** configuration, but nothing helped.
I also tried the [akka-sample-osgi-dining-hakkers](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/v2.2.3/akka-samples/akka-sample-osgi-dining-hakkers) example but I ran in an OSGi nightmare...
What am I missing?

Comment: I had a similar issue. Did you already consider to not extend your activator class by `ActorSystemActivator`? See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/scala-ide-dev/BMaezd5sTKs) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information from the link attached by sschaef (thank you) helped solve the issue. It's a workaround that makes possible start the Akka system without hacking the dependency libraries. As mentioned in that thread, apparently is a class loader issue, and the solution (that I followed) uses a listener to activate the system.

I still have extended ActorSystemActivator (although this can be avoided as pointed out by sschaef) and I reused the code from the extended class in the overridden start and stop methods. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
class Activator extends ActorSystemActivator {

  private var system: Option[ActorSystem] = None
  @volatile var bundleListener: org.osgi.framework.BundleListener = null

  def configure(bundleContext: BundleContext, system: ActorSystem): Unit = {}
  override def getActorSystemName(context: BundleContext): String = "my-actor-system"

  override def start(context: BundleContext) = {
    bundleListener = new org.osgi.framework.BundleListener() {
      override def bundleChanged(event: org.osgi.framework.BundleEvent) {
        if (event.getBundle == context.getBundle) {
          if (event.getType == org.osgi.framework.BundleEvent.STARTED) {
            system = Some(OsgiActorSystemFactory(context, getActorSystemConfiguration(context)).createActorSystem(Option(getActorSystemName(context))))
            system foreach (addLogServiceListener(context, _))
            system foreach (configure(context, _))
          }
        }
      }
    }
    context.addBundleListener(bundleListener)
  }

  override def stop(context: BundleContext) = {
    if (bundleListener != null)
      context.removeBundleListener(bundleListener)
    system foreach (_.shutdown())
  }
}
```